# Rewriting an expression while using another parameter

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, variable

I wish to rewrite V and M with the given A. I have provided what the end result is supposed to look like.

Here is V

```
V = -((S w δ μ + S γ δ μ + S δ μ^2 - V w γ δ σ)/(η (w + μ) (S + V σ) (μ + ψ)))
```

Here is M:

```
M = -((V w γ δ σ + V w δ μ σ + V γ δ μ σ + V δ μ^2 σ + S w δ ψ + S γ δ ψ + 
  S δ μ ψ + V w δ σ ψ + V γ δ σ ψ + V δ μ σ ψ)/(η (w + μ) (S + V σ) (μ + ψ)))
```

Here is the A:

```
A = (δ D (μ + γ))/(η (S + σ V))
```

Here is what the final form of V and M are supposed to look like:

```
V =  q/(μ + ψ) - A S/(D (μ + ψ))
```

and

```
M = W = (q ψ)/(μ (μ + ψ)) - A ψ Subscript[(S/(D μ (μ + ψ)) - σ A V/(D μ))
```

Sure I can use simplify on V and M and then manually manipulate by hand to get the end result but I am curious if this can be easily done in Mathematica. I have seen similar questions here but most of the ones I found people were just rewriting the entire expression in terms of another variable. Here I cannot rewrite V or M *only* in terms of A only so I think this is a little different.

Comment: I formatted the Greek symbols but it appears there's something missing after `Subscript` in the last equation.

Comment: Your definition of $V$ contains $V$. Is this on purpose (a self-consistent definition)?

Answer (score 1):

Not a full solution but an attempt at simplifying semi-automatically.

Calculate the [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) to look for useful equations. We start with the three given equalities for $V$, $M$, and $A$,

```
V + ((S w δ μ + S γ δ μ + S δ μ^2 - V w γ δ σ)/(η (w + μ) (S + V σ) (μ + ψ))) == 0
M + ((V w γ δ σ + V w δ μ σ + V γ δ μ σ + V δ μ^2 σ + S w δ ψ + S γ δ ψ + S δ μ ψ + V w δ σ ψ + V γ δ σ ψ + V δ μ σ ψ)/(η (w + μ) (S + V σ) (μ + ψ))) == 0
A - (δ D (μ + γ))/(η (S + σ V)) == 0
```

and transform them into a whole set of functions that have the same zeros,

```
G = GroebnerBasis[{V + ((S w δ μ + S γ δ μ + S δ μ^2 - V w γ δ σ)/(η (w + μ) (S + V σ) (μ + ψ))),
                   M + ((V w γ δ σ + V w δ μ σ + V γ δ μ σ + V δ μ^2 σ + S w δ ψ + S γ δ ψ + S δ μ ψ + V w δ σ ψ + V γ δ σ ψ + V δ μ σ ψ)/(η (w + μ) (S + V σ) (μ + ψ))),
                   A - (δ D (μ + γ))/(η (S + σ V))},
                  {V, M, A}] // FullSimplify
```

Some of the resulting functions give simple expressions when solved for $V$ or $M$:

```
Solve[G[[8]] == 0, V] // FullSimplify
(*    {{V -> (-A S η + D δ (γ + μ))/(A η σ)}}    *)

Solve[G[[7]] == 0, M] // FullSimplify
(*    {{M -> -V - (δ (w + γ + μ))/(η (w + μ))}}    *)
```

So we have $V=\frac{D\delta(\gamma+\mu)}{A\eta\sigma}-\frac{S}{\sigma}$ and $M=-V-\frac{\delta(\gamma+\mu+w)}{\eta(\mu+w)}$. These aren't exactly the expression you were looking for, but already look pretty simple.

Also, we have

```
Solve[G[[5]] == 0, M] // FullSimplify
(*    {{M -> (-((D δ (γ + μ))/η) + A (S - (δ (w + γ + μ) σ)/(η (w + μ))))/(A σ)}}    *)
```

thus expressing M as a function of A without involving V:
$$
M=-\frac{D \delta(\gamma+\mu)}{A\eta\sigma}+\frac{S}{\sigma}-\frac{\delta(\gamma+\mu+w)}{\eta(\mu+w)}
$$

Et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

I have replaced `D` with `d` since [`D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) has a specific meaning within Mathematica.

```
eqns = {V == -((S w δ μ + S γ δ μ + 
         S δ μ^2 - 
         V w γ δ σ)/(η (w + μ) (S + 
           V σ) (μ + ψ))),
   M == -((V w γ δ σ + V w δ μ σ + 
         V γ δ μ σ + V δ μ^2 σ + 
         S w δ ψ + S γ δ ψ + 
         S δ μ ψ + V w δ σ ψ + 
         V γ δ σ ψ + 
         V δ μ σ ψ)/(η (w + μ) (S + 
           V σ) (μ + ψ))),
   A == (δ d (μ + γ))/(η (S + σ V))};
```

The requested forms cannot be obtained since they contain a variable `q` which is not contained in the original equations.

```
param = Complement[Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]], {V, M, A}]

(* {d, S, w, γ, δ, η, μ, σ, ψ} *)

sol = Simplify[Solve[eqns, {V, M}, {#}][[1]] & /@ param];
```

Taking the solution with the lowest overall [`LeafCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html)

```
solVM = SortBy[sol, LeafCount][[1]]

(* {V -> (-A S η + d δ (γ + μ))/(A η σ), 
    M -> ((-A S η + d δ (γ + μ)) (-A σ + 
        d ψ))/(A d η μ σ)} *)
```

This gives the same result for `V` as the simplest (by `LeafCount`) expression for `V` among all of the solutions

```
solV = SortBy[sol[[All, 1]], LeafCount][[1]]

(* V -> (-A S η + d δ (γ + μ))/(A η σ) *)
```

However, there is a slightly simpler (by `LeafCount`) solution for `M`

```
solM = SortBy[sol[[All, 2]], LeafCount][[1]]

(* M -> (δ (w + γ + μ) (A σ - 
    d ψ))/(η (w + μ) (-A σ + d (μ + ψ))) *)

LeafCount /@ {solVM[[2]], solM}

(* {38, 36} *)
```